# What does exit(21) stand for? Can it be replaced with exit(1)?

Tags: c, exit-code

What does `exit(21)` stand for? Can it be replaced with exit(1)? I'm trying to understand exit codes and I wasn't able to find an answer to this question at all.

I've attached the sample code.

```
for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
        r= fork();
        if(r==0)
        {
            display(i);
            exit(21);
        }
```

Comment: No code shown, no context.  21 could mean anything.  It could be the age of the developer when they wrote the code, or his favorite Vegas pastime.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know whether submitting code for this problem would've been helpful. I've posted a sample code.

Comment: OK.  Error code 21 apparently means that the result of a `fork()` operation was zero.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811317/102937) for more details about how the return result of fork works.

Comment: So does this mean that it is equal to exit(0)?

Comment: No, it means what I said it means.  You seem to think there is a "standard" for these codes; there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

A program's exit code is used to determine if the program succeeded or failed, and if it failed then why.  The exit code for a program is specified by either passing the value to the `exit` function or by returning the value from the `main` function.

By convention, an exit value of 0 represents success while values greater than 0 indicate failure.  As to what a particular exit value means, that is defined by the program in question and (other than 0 for success) is different for each program.

You'll need to look more at the code that uses exit value 21 to figure out what that code means.

In the code sample you provided, the code calls `exit(21)` when `fork` returns 0.  The `fork` function creates a child process and returns twice: once to the parent with the pid of the child, and once to the child with the value 0.  So *in this particular case*, the exit value 21 is what is returned from the child process.  But again, that's for *this program*.  Other programs are free to use this value for some other situation.